# iOS 8.0: NSUserDefaults resets

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nsuserdefaults

Since iOS 8.x the UserDefaults has a strange behavior. Whenever I "quit" my app via the app-switcher my userdefaults gets reseted.

On iOS 7.x it works like a charm, so hope you guys can help me.

Some Code from the App Delegate:

```
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FirstStart"])
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"FirstStart"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"FirstStart"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
```

This is one example. I have some more code snippets, where I store something to the userdefaults (mostly bools) and everytime it's reseted.

When I start from xCode there is no problem.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is this via simulator or device? I've noticed problems using NSUserDefaults on the simulator since xcode6.

Comment: The problem appears via device

Comment: Ugh, that is some bad news. Have you checked radar?

Comment: What do you mean with "radar"?

Comment: Sorry, apple's awful bug reporter https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login.html?appIdKey=77e2a60d4bdfa6b7311c854a56505800be3c24e3a27a670098ff61b69fc5214b&sslEnabled=true&rv=3

Comment: Now after some debug sessions I've found that the UserDefaults get deleted automatically. I don't know why. But once I use the app and close it via the app-selector view the userdefualts get deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KILL ME!!!

In my AppDelegate Method applicatinWillTerminate:application I called

NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];

I don't know why I remove the UserDefaults but anyway now it works fine!

Comment: oops :) Well, like I said keep an eye out for the simulator not resetting userdefaults when you delete an app from it, as that is definitely an issue now.